# System.Threading.Task Wait doubt

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, task, multitasking

If I am using `System.Threading.Task` to run parallel tasks like this:

```
Func<MyResult> func=ComputeResult;

var t = Task.Facroty.StartNew<MyResult>(ComputeResult, 1);//1 is some id
t.Wait();
var tt = Task.Facroty.StartNew<MyResult>(ComputeResult, 2);
tt.Wait();
```

Will `t.Wait()` block next statement.

If I am starting few tasks in a loop and want to wait for them all in such a way that tasks inside loop don't block eachother but statement after loop is blocked.

I am using following construct:

```
var tasks=new List<Task<MyResult>>();

Func<MyResult> func=ComputeResult;

for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
    var t=Task.Facroty.StartNew<MyResult>(ComputeResult, i);
    tasks.Add(t);
    //t.Wait(); //SHOULD I CALL WAIT HERE?
}

 //OR THIS BETTER OR EVEN IF THIS WORKS
 foreach(var t in tasks)
 {
      t.Wait();
 }

 //do other stuff
```

EDIT:- In final form I am using following line instead of last `foreach` loop.

```
 Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Task.WaitAll(
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 10)
        .Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(arg => 
        {
            // Do the task here
            // arg will obviously be the state object x
            // which will range from 1 to 10
        }, x))
        .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: good suggestion. The Ids come from datatable and will try this tomorrow. I don't need `ToArray`, but I might need to support cancelation.